# Minibuffer not showing the bottom line

Tags: frames, minibuffer, ivy

When I use multiple monitors, the bottom line of the minibuffer doesn't render; ie there's a line at the bottom of the list that I can select but doesn't render on screen.

I'm pretty stumped on how to figure out what could be breaking, but I suspect it might be ivy-related. My window manager is i3, but I'm doubtful that matters.

What should I check to debug this?

Comment: Although I don't know for sure what the cause is, here's something easy to try: `(setq frame-resize-pixelwise t)`

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, then bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, then consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior with i3 and didn't experience it before switching from XFCE. Opening a terminal window will cause emacs to resize, and the minibuffer reappears. (I'd make this a comment but I don't have the rep, maybe a friendly moderator can assist)